# JavaのArrayListでの領域確保方法について

Tags: java, arraylist

JavaのArrayListでは、「初期化時に確保するサイズを指定する」「ArrayList#ensureCapacityを使う」ことで、あらかじめ領域を確保できますよね？

```
ArrayList<Integer> hoge = new ArrayList<Integer>(100); //確保1
hoge.ensureCapacity(100); //確保2
```

しかしどちらの書き方でも、C++でのstd::vectorにおけるreserve()のように「領域を確保する」だけであって、resize()のように「要素数が増える」わけじゃありませんよね。つまり、ArrayList#addで後ろに要素を追加はできるものの、ArrayList#setで特定位置に値を代入しようとするとIndexOutOfBoundsExceptionが生じてしまうのです。
　現在ではArrayList#addとforループでとりあえず全要素に0を敷き詰めて対処していますが、もっと綺麗に書く方法は無いものでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tai2` さんの回答と同じ事をしていますが、以下の様にも書けます。

```
ArrayList<Integer> hoge = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[100]));
```

ただ、`nCopies` と異なって初期化はされません。

```
hoge.set(0, 0);
System.out.println(hoge);
=>
[0, null, null, ...
```

Comment: こちらもありがとうございます。初期化する必要が無い際はこちらでも良さそうですね。

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> l = Collections.nCopies(5, 123) // 123,123,123,123,123
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList(l); // もしArrayListが良ければ
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T)

Comment: ありがとうございます。Listを使って初期化すれば良いのですね。

Answer (score 1):

Stream が使える場合は、以下のように書けます。

```
List<Integer> list = Stream.generate(() -> 0).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` の方が、出題(?) である arraylist の制約を満たしますね。